# JOIN show row even if it is null

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my code:

```
SELECT *, cr.club_winner AS 'club_winner', COUNT(club_winner) AS 'count_cw'
FROM clubs c
JOIN club_results cr 
WHERE c.club_id = cr.club_winner AND c.club_group = '1'
GROUP BY cr.club_winner
ORDER BY count_cw DESC, club_name
```

I have in one table rows with club names and in the second table club_winner id's. In the table, I want to show live standings and if club never was a winner it displayed '0'. Not sure what to do.

Right now it displays only clubs which were winners at least once.

I have tried to add 'case', but id didn't work

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Start with `LEFT JOIN`.  I think the query you want is something like this:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(cr.club_winner) AS count_wins
FROM clubs c LEFT JOIN
     club_results cr 
     ON c.club_id = cr.club_winner 
WHERE c.club_group = '1'
GROUP BY c.club_id
ORDER BY count_cw DESC, club_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `where` clause to an `on` clause and change your join to a `left join`:

```
SELECT *, cr.club_winner AS 'club_winner', COUNT(club_winner) AS 'count_cw'
FROM clubs c
LEFT JOIN club_results cr ON c.club_id = cr.club_winner AND c.club_group = '1'
GROUP BY cr.club_winner
ORDER BY count_cw DESC, club_name
```

Comment: i think  alias  name should not enclosed by single quotes .

Answer (score 0):

you should use left join if you don't have values in second table

```
SELECT *, cr.club_winner AS club_winner, COUNT(club_winner) AS count_cw
FROM clubs c
LEFT JOIN club_results cr on c.club_id = cr.club_winner AND c.club_group = '1'

GROUP BY cr.club_winner
ORDER BY count_cw DESC, club_name
```

Comment: i think  alias name should not enclosed by single quotes .

Comment: @JYoThI  correct .. single quote removed .. and in this case are not necessary